# Create a .so file with everything statically linked(include libc) in CMake

Tags: c, cmake, cross-compiling

I want to create a .so shared object that statically linked with musl libc(or some other libc). So that others can dynamically linked with my .so file during runtime without worrying having certain libc on their platform. Is this possible ? If so, how can I achieve this in CMake ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this by statically linking to dependent libraries in your shared library and making such linkage private (i.e. `target_link_libraries(MyLib PRIVATE dependencies...)`).

Then you will have to ensure that *no part* of any of the dependent libraries is exposed to a consumer of your shared library (including any headers counts as exposure). The [PImpl](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl) technique will probably be of use to you.

Comment: Do I need to add 'libc' in the target_link_libraries ? like  target_link_libraries(MyLub PRIVATE libc.so)

Comment: You may need to use the cmake target (if possible). Also, the libc library must be built statically and not have other external dependencies for this to work.